# Getting "You don't have permission to access that port" error in Django

Tags: android, django, retrofit, hosting

I want to run my Django API to my IP address which is 192.168.1.5:81 with port number but I am getting that `You don't have permission to access that port`.

I have done port forwarding in my router.
I am doing this because I want to get data in my Android application using retrofit.

[image: screenshot of the error]

Comment: Can you run on a different port?

Comment: can you tell me on which port

Comment: Something like 8080?

Comment: @IainShelvington okay so i tried with 8080 and its giving me error.......Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '192.168.1.5:8080'. You may need to add '192.168.1.5' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Answer (score 0):

i checked my available ports on my IP address then i ran code with the open port and solved this.
also i added my IP address inside ALLOWED_HOSTs in settings.py file